# Run LineageOS on raspberri Pi4 without HDMI connected

Tags: android, android-things

I installed Lineage OS 18.1 (a based on Android 11 operating system) on my raspberry pi4.
When connected to a monitor via HDMI, it boots normally.
After booting normally, disconnecting the HDMI results in the OS not responding anymore.
Booting without HDMI doesn't work at all.

I can verify that LineageOS is active when no HDMI is connected by using the "adb devices" command, which is an Android debugging command which shows active devices. In addition, the leds are blinking as well.

So the OS is active, but doesn't work properly without HDMI connected to a monitor

I would like to use LineageOS without a HDMI connected, and I think there are two ways to do this:

- Make the Raspberry Pi4 think that a HDMI is connected to a monitor programmatically
- Make the LineageOS able to run the OS without an HDMI connected

Anyone have been able to figure out one of these solutions or knows another solution?

I've tried to:

- set hdmi_force_hotplug=1 in config.txt